# Router configuration: Can i configure the WAN port of my router to static ip, at the same time LAN port to static in different local network?

Tags: router, ip, wifi-configuration, wan

Can i change my WAN port IP to be static IP in my local network? LAN IP is already static and it is in a different local network. For example:

- **WAN** IP: 192.168.250.2 / 255.255.255.0
- **LAN** IP: 192.168.1.5 / 255.255.255.0

Is the above configuration valid?

With the above configuration, I connected an external Windows PC to router SSID. Then I tried to ping the router from windows. But it is not pinging.
(The Windows PC is Wifi connected to router)

Answer (score 0):

No (unless you use the wrong terminology and you actually mean s.th. else).

The WAN IP is the IP address you get assigned from your ISP or in your case who ever provides the internet to you (it's very unlikely your provider uses 192.168.250.0/24 to assign WAN IPs). The WAN IP does not have to be in the same network segment as your LAN IP. Your router will handle the traffic between them.

If by WAN IP you actually mean your routers IP, then you might be able to change it. Depends on the router, some do not allow that. But in this case I would recommend to enable DCHP or set your LAN IP to the same segment your router runs on (e.g. 192.168.250.3 if it's not yet taken).